# How to find code of function

Tags: javascript, function, events, find, chap-links-library

Here I have an example: http://jsbin.com/oLaqoToH/5 (timeline with events)
On double click I can create a new event but my problem is how to find function that do this so how to find the code that is created for this action.

This example also have external resources (engine) timeline.js
http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/timeline/timeline.js

I was try with `onNew(); new Item.` and so, but nothing of that is not a answer... Documentation is bad and I dont know how this actally work.

Help?

Comment: Most likely all the needed code is in the JS file, open it and see.

Comment: I open but I dont see where is that function I cant find her... this is my problem, I try all day to find it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
/**
 * Double click event occurred for an item
 * @param {Event}  event
 */
links.Timeline.prototype.onDblClick = function (event) {
    var params = this.eventParams,
        options = this.options,
        dom = this.dom,
        size = this.size;
    event = event || window.event;

    if (params.itemIndex != undefined) {
        var item = this.items[params.itemIndex];
        if (item && this.isEditable(item)) {
            // fire the edit event
            this.trigger('edit');
        }
    }
    else {
        if (options.editable) {
            // create a new item

            // get mouse position
            params.mouseX = links.Timeline.getPageX(event);
            params.mouseY = links.Timeline.getPageY(event);
            var x = params.mouseX - links.Timeline.getAbsoluteLeft(dom.content);
            var y = params.mouseY - links.Timeline.getAbsoluteTop(dom.content);

            // create a new event at the current mouse position
            var xstart = this.screenToTime(x);
            var xend = this.screenToTime(x  + size.frameWidth / 10); // add 10% of timeline width
            if (options.snapEvents) {
                this.step.snap(xstart);
                this.step.snap(xend);
            }

            var content = options.NEW;
            var group = this.getGroupFromHeight(y);   // (group may be undefined)
            var preventRender = true;
            this.addItem({
                'start': xstart,
                'end': xend,
                'content': content,
                'group': this.getGroupName(group)
            }, preventRender);
            params.itemIndex = (this.items.length - 1);
            this.selectItem(params.itemIndex);

            this.applyAdd = true;

            // fire an add event.
            // Note that the change can be canceled from within an event listener if
            // this listener calls the method cancelAdd().
            this.trigger('add');

            if (this.applyAdd) {
                // render and select the item
                this.render({animate: false});
                this.selectItem(params.itemIndex);
            }
            else {
                // undo an add
                this.deleteItem(params.itemIndex);
            }
        }
    }

    links.Timeline.preventDefault(event);
};
```

[source](http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/timeline/timeline.js)